# how unbox object into actual object by name of class

Tags: reflection, f#, f#-data

I want do unboxing of object to its actual type by using name of actual object.

```
type Employee = {
    Id:int
    Name:string
}
let defEmployee = {
    Id=1
    Name="Mahi"
}

//actual object
let actualObject = defEmployee
let empAsObject = actualObject :> obj // type with casted in base class
let actualObject = unbox(empAsObject) //here I am trying to unboxing but not 
   able to do it.
```

I can do it when I have actual type of object run-time but I have only name of type/object

Comment: You can't cast without a type to cast to, what are you planning on doing with `actualObject` if you don't know the type?

Comment: I have called this method moduleInfo.GetMethod("methodName").Invoke(null, args), I am getting return type object type, which i want to convert object into actual type of object.

Comment: Do you know what the return type of `methodName` is? If so you can just cast. If you don't know what it is then you need to explain what you're trying to do with the result.

Comment: I am creating one framework which calls to multiple methods and it applies all the types. By ignoring performance I am concentrating on effort to write it.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question - what exactly are you trying to do with `actualObject` that you cannot?

Comment: I have to pass this objects to other functions parameter. This is generic function so i can`t put any type there.

Comment: What's the type of the other function(s)? Please add them to your question.

Answer (score 5):

The `unbox` function casts an obj to a type `'T`. To do this it needs to know which type to cast to. Often this can be worked out with type inference from the surrounding context, but in this case the compiler does not have that information. Therefore you need to provide the type. One way of doing that is to explicitly pass the type argument to `unbox`:

```
let actualEmployee = unbox<Employee> empAsObject
```

Note that the `unbox` operation is unsafe. It will throw a runtime exception if the value is not actually an `Employee`. This is the risk you take whenever you decide to step outside of the type system and box values.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way the compiler can deduce what the concrete subtype would be, in general. If you lost type information, you have to coerce it back in (at the risk of throwing an exception):

`let actualObject = empAsObject :?> Employee`